# JPA Inheritance demanding ID in subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I'm working on a project with Struts2 along with JPA with Hibernate.

I have two entities User (id,email) and Customer (user_id).
Since it's natural to think that every Customer is a User I had the Customer Inherit from the user. Here's the relevant code of the entities:

**User:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String email;
    ...getters and setters...
}
```

**Customer**

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.getByCustomerUserId", query = "SELECT C FROM Customer C where C.id=:id")
})
public class Customer extends User implements Serializable {
}
```

If I run the query *Customer.getByCustomerUserId* I keep getting the error:

> Unknown column 'customer0_.id' in 'where clause'

I tried following the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415488/jpa-inheritance-demands-id-in-subclass) by creating a BaseEntity having the Id field and having the User Entity inherit from it but there's no effect. I still keep getting this error message. Can someone Please tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: There is no `id` property in `Customer` class.

Comment: A few things are strange here: you are using "user" as the table name, which database should not permit, and Customer doesn't have @Entity annotation. Aside from that, query works fine for me, when the required parameter is set. Is Hibernate generating the tables, or are they already created?

Comment: @AleksandrM: There doesn't need to be an id property in the Customer class because I am inheriting it from the User class.

Comment: @alterfox: Sorry, I forgot to paste the '@Entity' portion of the code here. I do realise that the database shouldn't be allowing a "user" as the table name but it seems to work fine with MySQL. Also, the tables and the data is already existing in the database. Hibernate just interacts with it.

Comment: @alterfox: I've also tried renaming the table to 'users' instead of 'user', but there still no change.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there is no reference in the customer table to the user table, or there is something similar off with the constraints.
I suggest that you rename your entity classes and let Hibernate generate tables from them. Then use your query on the new entities, and if you have no problems, you should inspect the differences between the new tables and the existing ones (use 'Create table script' option in some DB tool).

Answer (score 0):

Drop primaryKeyJoinColumn statement.

Then insert @ForeignKey(name="CHOOSE_A_NAME").
Generate your ddl and run it (with the constraints)

By default, inheritance mecanisms will use the Pk defined in superClass ( whatever his name)
ENjoy